# What is the way to upload bulk images in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image

I have more than 500 images and I want to upload in WordPress media, I tried through FTP, WordPress changed images in different dimensions, and when I installed plugin "ADD TO SERVER " it uploads all the files. 
I just want to add original images in the WordPress dashboard. Is there any way to upload bulk files in the WordPress media?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through FTP but go to settings before and change to import ORIGINAL size instead change dimensions.
You can find it under SETTINGS --> Media.

I have use 1024/1024 as max to avoid overload the server. You can change it on 2K(2048) or 4K(4096).

Comment: I fond now your comment, I sort it with uploading images one by one. 
I tried this, and it works. 
It takes me 2 days :(. Thank you for your answer. In future I'll definitely use this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`intermediate_image_sizes_advanced`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/intermediate_image_sizes_advanced/) hook to prevent WordPress from getting the list of image sizes it normally uses.

The following code will feed an empty array to WordPress instead of the registered list of image sizes:

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', function(){
    return [];
}, 10, 2 );
```

Running the `Add to server` plugin again after adding that code to your `functions.php` should not resize your uploaded images.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. But after using this function, and when I'll add all images to my gallery, then this function must be removed because in future it will stop wordpress default behavior? Am I right.?

Comment: That's exact. WordPress will not resize any image you're uploading while this function is present. Remove it after you're done with the bulk upload.